# Is it possible to get a reference to a WCF ServiceHost Singleton Instance before the first WCF client request comes in?

Tags: .net, wcf

I am trying to access the singleton instance created by my WCF service but `.SingletonInstance` seems to be null even after `.Open` is called on the `ServiceHost`.

Is there any way to force the `ServiceHost` to create the instance before the first WCF client request comes in (which presumably automatically spawns the singleton instance)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the service call itself...
The instance is indeed only created when a request comes in, you can't access what isn't there yet.

But seriously, try to work around this. What do you need it for that you can't do in the constructor of the implementing class?

Comment: Thanks for confirming that (and that's an interesting idea about calling itself).  I'm trying to add listeners to an event that exists in the singleton so that I can keep the singleton as reusable as possible.  Happy to look at an alternative if this is the incorrect approach with WCF.  Long story short I'm trying to produce some statistics on a windows form based on the requests coming in.

Comment: "What do you need it for that you can't do in the constructor?" Dependency injection. WCF makes it hard to do constructor injection so I wanted to initialize the service's properties via `SingletonInstance`.

Answer (score 10):

I know this question is a bit old, but I'm facing a similar problem and think I found a solution. There is an version of the ServiceHost constructor that takes a reference to the instance, rather than the type:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms585487.aspx#Y342

So you can create the instance first, and then pass it to the ServiceHost constructor.  I haven't tried this yet, but it looks like it should do the trick. Be sure to read the remarks about releasing the instance. when you use this constructor.

Comment: This should be the choosen answer.

Comment: I know this answer is a  bit old, but i am facing the same problem now. I tried the alternate constructor, the host opens without error, but the client cannot connect to it anymore.  Did you get this working ? If so, an example would be so great

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help you. I have not worked with WCF in a few years and do not have access to the relevant source code. I only know that I did get it working with this constructor, but I don't remember any of the details.

Comment: If you find the constructor works but you get a failure in your server a bit later on, make sure your server is configured as *Single Instance*.
`var behaviour = serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceBehaviorAttribute>();
                    behaviour.InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single;`

Answer (score 0):

....you might be able to do crazy things with a custom IInstanceContextProvider...guess this is not worth it though....

Answer (score 0):

You can use the constructor of your class and store instance object when it is created by wcf servicehost